# Some questions coming from application programming (C#/Visual C++) to ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

At the new place I am working, I've been tasking with developing a web-application framework.  I am new (6 months ish) to the ASP.NET framework and things seem pretty straight forward, but I have a few questions that I'd like to ask you ASP professionals.  I'll note that I am no stranger to C#.

**Long life objects/Caching**

What is the preferred method to deal with objects that you don't want to re-initialize every time a page is it?  I noticed that there was a cache manager that can be used, but are there any caveats to using this?  For example, I might want to cache various things and I was thinking about writing a wrapper around the cache that prefixed cache names so that I could implement different caches using the same underlying .NET cache manager.

1) Are there any design considerations I need to think about the objects that I am want to cache?

2) If I want to implement a manager of some time that is around during the lifetime of the web application (thread-safe, obviously), is it enough to initialize it during app_start and kill it in app_end?  Or is this practiced frowned upon and any managers are created uniquely in the constructor/init method of the page being served.

3) If I have a long-term object initialized at app start, is this likely to get affected when the app pool is recycled?  If it is destroy at app end is it a case of it simply getting destroyed and then recreated again?  I am fine with this restriction, I just want to get a little clearer :)

**Long Life Threads**

I've done a bit of research on this and this question is probably redundant.  It seems it is not safe to start a worker thread in the ASP.NET environment and instead, use a windows service to do long-running tasks.  The latter isn't exactly a problem, the target environments will have the facility to install services, but I just wanted to double check that this was absolutely necessary.  I understand threads can throw exceptions and die, but I do not understand the reasoning behind prohibiting them.  If .NET provided a a thread framework that encompassed System.Thread, but also provided notifications for when the Application Server was going to recycle the App-Pool, we could actually do something about it rather than just keel over and die at the point we were stopped.

Are there any solutions to threading in ASP.NET or is it basically "service"?

I am sure I'll have more queries, but this is it for now.

EDIT: Thankyou for all the responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the main thing that you're going to want to keep in mind. The IIS may get reset or may reset itself (based on criteria) while you're working. You can never know when that will happen unless it stops rendering your page while you're waiting on the response (in which case you'll get a browser notice that the page stopped responding, eventually.

## Threads

This is why you shouldn't use threads in ASP.NET apps. However, that's not to say you can't. Once again, you'll need to configure the IIS engine properly (I've had it hang when spawning a lot of threads, but that may have been machine dependent). If you can trust that nobody will cause ASP.NET to recompile your code/restart your application (by *saving* the `web.config`, for instance) then you will have less issues than you might otherwise.

Instead of running a Windows service, you could use an ASMX or WCF service which also run on IIS/.NET. That's up to you. But with multiple service pools it allows you to keep everything "in the same environment" as far as installations and builds are concerned. They obviously don't share the same processpool/memoryspace.

### "You're Wrong!"

I'm sure someone will read this far and go "but you can't thread in ASP.NET!!!" so here's the link that shows you how to do it from that venerable MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx

Now onto **Long life objects/Caching**

## Caching

So it depends on what you mean by caching. Is this per user, per system, per application, per database, or per page? Each is possible, but takes some contrivance and complexity, depending on needs.

The simplest way to do it per page is with static variables. This is also highly dangerous if you're using it for user-code-stuff because there's no indication to the end user that the variable is going to change, if more than one users uses the page. Instead, if you need something to live with the user while they work with the page in particular, you could either stuff it into session (serverside caching, stays with the user, they can use it across multiple pages) or you could stick it into ViewState.

The cachemanager you reference above would be good for application style caching, where everyone using the webapp can use the same datastore. That might be good for intensive queries where you want to get the values back as quickly as possible so long as they're not stale. That's up to you to decide. Also, things like application settings could be stored there, if you use a database layer for storage.

### Long term cache objects

You could initialize it in the app_start with no problem, and the same goes for destroying it at the end if you felt the need, but yes, you do need to watch out for what I described at first about the system throwing all your code out and restarting.

## Keel over and die

But you don't get notified when you're (the app pool here) going to be restarted (as far as I know) so you can pretty much keel over and die on anything. Always assume the app is going to go down on you before your request, and that every request is the first one.

Really tho, that just leads back into web-design in the first place. You don't know that this is the first visitor or the fifty millionth (unless you're storing that information in memory of course) so just like the app is stateless, you also need to plan your architecture to be stateless as much as possible. That's where web-apps are great.

If you need state on a regular basis, consider sticking with desktop apps. If you can live with stateless-ness, welcome to ASP.NET and web development.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth response.  I don't really have a choice about sticking to desktop apps (though my personal feelings on that are for another discussion :) ).  Yes, the CacheManager would basically cut down on some database queries on content that is rarely changed.  With regard to "assume it's the first hit", should I strategize around the idea that "If manager X isn't there, go go go manager X"?  That way whatever happens, some request, somewhere is going to put the manager back in to play?

Comment: Yes but be aware of concurrency design as well. You can't know that there won't be two users nearly simultaneously. All you can do is all you can do. I wouldn't worry too much about that tho, until you find it to be a problem. Just be aware of it initially. ~ Also, I happen to prefer webapps over desktop apps ;)

Comment: I wouldn't say "If you can trust that nobody will cause ASP.NET to recompile your code/restart your application" as that is ALWAYS possible (hey, it's going to restart at some point). Rather, I'd say that you should make sure that said threading code is resilient in the face of it happening.

Comment: @JonHanna ~ I agree, and you notice the rest of that comment was effectively "you should have less to worry about" and yet I continuously commented about the hazards of the threading model and to make sure that the system could operate stateless-ly. +1 from me to you sir.

Answer (score 3):

1) The main thing about caching is understanding the lifetime of the cache, and the effects of caching (particularly large) objects in cache.  Consider caching a 1MB object in memory that is generated each time your default.aspx page is hit; and after a year of production you're getting 10,000 hits an hour, and object lifetime is 2 hours.  You can easily chew up TONS of memory, which can affect performance, and also may cause things to be prematurely expired from the cache, which in turn can cause other issues.  As long as you understand the effects of all of this, you're fine.

2) Starting it up in Application_Start and shutting it down in Application_End is fine.  You can also implement a custom HttpApplication with an http module.

3) Yes, when your app pool is recycled it calls Application_End and everything is shutdown and destroyed.

4) (Threads)  The issue with threads comes up in relation to scaling.  If you hit that default.aspx page, and it fires up a thread, and that page gets hit 10,000 in 2 minutes, you could potentially have a ton of threads running in your application pool.  Again, as long as you understand the ramifications of firing up a thread, you can do it.  ThreadPool is another story, the asp.net runtime uses the ThreadPool to process requests, so if you tie up all the threadpool threads, your application can potentially hang because there isn't a thread available to process the request.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The items I'll be caching are way under 1MB.  It was mostly around product/content data (eCommerce/CMS, respectively) rather than dragging it from the database every time.  I was thinking of implementing time-out policies for stuff that wasn't accessed very much.  Regarding threads, I was thinking of having a job thread (just one) that pages can "post" work to, such as mass-emailing, without resorting to a service.

Comment: Something like an email or job "thread" is very suitable for a ASMX/WCF service, which could live on the same box, same website even, but be assigned to a different AppPool.  But spinning up one or two threads isn't going to be a big deal (just don't use ThreadPool) imo.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Are there any design considerations I need to think about the objects that I am want to cache?
>
> 2) If I want to implement a manager of some time that is around during the lifetime of the web application (thread-safe, obviously), is it enough to initialize it during app_start and kill it in app_end? Or is this practiced frowned upon and any managers are created uniquely in the constructor/init method of the page being served.

There's a difference between data caching and output caching.  I think you're looking for data caching which means caching some object for use in the application.  This can be done via HttpContext.Current.Cache.  You can also cache page output and differentiate that on conditions so the page logic doesn't have to run at all.  This functionality is also built into ASP.NET.  Something to keep in mind when doing data caching is that you need to be careful about the scope of the things you cache.  For example, when using Entity Framework, you might be tempted to cache some object that's been retrieved from the DB.  However, if your DB Context is scoped per request (a new one for every user visiting your site, probably the correct way) then your cached object will rely on this DB Context for lazy loading but the DB Context will be disposed of after the first request ends.

> 3) If I have a long-term object initialized at app start, is this likely to get affected when the app pool is recycled? If it is destroy at app end is it a case of it simply getting destroyed and then recreated again? I am fine with this restriction, I just want to get a little clearer :)

Perhaps the biggest issue with threading in ASP.NET is that it runs in the same process as all your requests.  Even if this weren't an issue in and of itself, IIS can be configured (and if you don't own the servers almost certainly will be configured) to shut down the app if it's inactive (which you mentioned) which can cause issues for these threads.  I have seen solutions to that including making sure IIS never recycles the app pool to spawning a thread that hits the site to keep it alive even on hosted servers